# String Parsing using tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to parse a string to return the text between two sets. For example, my string is: "faultstring>Item not valid: The specified Standard SIP1 Profile was not found faultstring>"

I want to write a function that will return the string: Item not valid: The specified Standard SIP1 Profile was not found

I am new to tcl and your help is very much appreciated.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no `faultstring>` inside the interesting string, and there might be some uninteresting garbage before and after specified fragment:

```
set testString "faultstring>Item not valid: The specified Standard SIP1 Profile was not found faultstring>"

if {[regexp {faultstring>(.*)faultstring>} $testString _ extracted]} {
     puts "Got it: $extracted"
}
```

The answer may vary for other assumptions.